# Deleting mySQL row with php

Tags: php, mysql

I'm trying to delete a row in a mySQL table 'users'. It's supposed to delete a users account when a linked button is clicked it takes them to this delete.php page. However, instead of bringing me back to the login page, it keeps me signed in to the account that's supposed to be deleted. I've tried a few other variations however it either doesn't delete the account or returns an error depending on how I wrote it.

```
<?php
// Initialize the session
session_start();

require_once "config.php";

 //delete the mySQL row
 if(isset($_SESSION["loggedin"]) && $_SESSION["loggedin"] === true){
    $sql = "DELETE FROM users WHERE id = 'id'";
    mysqli_query($link, $sql);
    header("location: login.php");
    exit;
}
?>
```

The same thing happens when I try this:

```
<?php
// Initialize the session
session_start();

include "config.php";
$id = $_REQUEST["id"];

//delete the mySQL row
$sql="DELETE FROM users WHERE id='$id'";
mysqli_query($sql);
header("location: login.php");
exit;
?>
```

Comment: Enable error-reporting, and you'll see why. You're missing some parameters to some functions here.

Comment: `mysqli_query($link, $sql);` OK `mysqli_query($sql);` Not OK, missing parameter. So this is a typo

Comment: _“it keeps me signed in to the account that's supposed to be deleted”_ - of course it does, because that info is stored in the session … and it doesn’t magically disappear from there, just because you deleted something from the database. You need to set `$_SESSION["loggedin"]` to false at least; better yet, destroy the whole session.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Please use link identifier in `mysqli_query`.

Code should be as below:

```
<?php
// Initialize the session
session_start();

include "config.php";
$id = $_REQUEST["id"];

//delete the mySQL row
$sql="DELETE FROM users WHERE id=".$id;
mysqli_query($link,$sql);
header("location: login.php");
exit;
?>
```

You should destroy session using `session_destroy()` or `session_unset()` before redirection.

Comment: Thanks, it worked! I just had to change it from $sql="DELETE FROM users WHERE id=".$id; to $sql="DELETE FROM users WHERE id=".$_SESSION['id'];

Answer (score 1):

In the second code, you forget put `$link` in `mysqli_query($sql)`